# How to redeploy soa projects to a managed node using Weblogic Enterprise Manager

Tags: deployment, cloud, soa, weblogic11g, bpel

I have configured a Soa Cluster with one admin node and two managed nodes and all server nodes configured in three different machines. once I deploy a Bpell to one managed node it automatically deploys in the other managed nodes as well(default behavior).  once you go to soa enterprise manager those deployed Bpels can be viewed under [Soa -> managed node -> Defult ->..]. It is the same place where we deploy new Bpels. I accidentally undeploy all bpels (you can do it by right clicking a managed node and choosing un-deploy option).

Now I'm having a hard time to get back to previous state, how to deploy all those projects again to a specific managed node. I tried to restart the node hoping it would sync again, yet the managed server went to "admin" state (not the ok state). 
is there anything needs to be done !!

Thanks, Hemal

Comment: there was a exception as <cb0f82a77acd36b6:-3b283e13:14cdb9ce977:-8000-0000000000000003> <1429613697535> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application 'OracleAppsAdapter' due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/tip/adapter/db/ox/apps/AppsInstanceFactory.
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/tip/adapter/db/ox/apps/AppsInstanceFactory. is there anyone familiar such exception

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to start the server from command line, it will work.

For managing 'managed servers' from EM or WLS console, there's one additional step that's needed during instalation process.

Please modify the nodemanager.properties of WLS and set the property startscriptenabled=true.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/core.1111/e10105/start.htm#CIHBACFI